# Why does Id altered from 1 to 1 happen using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a mapping like this

```
<class name="UserFileSummary" table="UserFile" lazy="false">
   <id name="FileId" column="UserFileId" type="int">
      <generator class="identity" />
   </id>...
```

and a property in the c# object like this

```
public long FileId { get; set; }
```

What I don't understand is why when I get an instance using

```
var myFile = session.Get<UserFileSummary>(id)
```

change a field value and then save it like this

```
myFile.myProperty = newValue
session.Save(myFile)
```

I get an error saying the the Id have been altered from 1 to 1. There are some posts around about this, but this is a simple int column (identity 1, 1). I must have made some basic error, please can anyone help out. Thanks

I've added this bit as an edit as the question turns out to be a non question

> The FileId property is type long, and the mapping is type int, that is why altered from 1 to 1 is a problem.

Please give me some feedback if you want me to delete this question, thanks everyone :)

Comment: Do you have a complete class mapping that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I could make up some mapping, but I was hoping to avoid lots of code posting to keep the question as useful as possible. There is nothing strange about the rest of the class, just string and int fields.

Comment: Just wanted something short that I could run, was also wondering if there was a property mapping to the Id as well, which would confuse nhibernate.

Comment: Thanks Keeper, sorry for sounding negative. There is a property mapped to the Id. I notice that claudio has suggested save or update, I've tried this, but I'll have another look. I am using the session through a repository pattern, so to say I'm using session.save is a bit of a synthesis. Thanks again :)

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in my case was due to the data type being a long (int64) in the database and being mapped to an int (int32) in the mapping. This meant that the real value changed whenever the object was saved, thus breaking the identifier. Thanks to everyone who helped out.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can point out from your code is the use of `Save` for updating an existing entity.

You could avoid calling explicitly the Save method for an entity that's alredy present on the session. Your changes will be automatically persisted when you flush the session.

If you insist to explicitly call the update method I'd say you should use `SaveOrUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks, I am using a repository pattern, so I don't really call save. Not sure what is causing this. :)

Comment: When I was removing the private setter stuff, I noticed that the id field was a long data type. Obviously the message "altered from 1 to 1" makes sense in this context and would be a problem. Now I have it all as int it works fine using my repository pattern. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: No problem :) glad that you finally figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

First, make the setter on the property private; the project will fail to compile if you have any code that mistakenly sets it. This is a good practice anyway. But it's not foolproof because there could be code inside the class that sets it, so you'll have to check for that.

```
public int FileId { get; private set; }
```

Second, closely examine the mapping file to make sure that you haven't mapped the field twice.

Comment: that needs to be <code>protected</code> for NHibernate to pick it up.

Comment: No it doesn't. NHibernate sets the properties using reflection so it can access a private setter. All of my objects that use identity keys have private setters.

Comment: Hmm, tried it, but it messes a lot of other stuff up, and I have loads of other projects where Id is read write, with no issues.

Comment: When I was removing the private setter stuff, I noticed that the id field was a long data type. Obviously the message "altered from 1 to 1" makes sense in this context and would be a problem. Now I have it all as int it works fine using my repository pattern. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: In my opinion, an identifier with a non-private setter in an NHibernate application using database generated (identity) IDs is a significant design flaw. But I'm glad you were able to find the problem.